# Trigger (MYSQL) with if-then-else doesn't works

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers

I have this trigger that **doesn't insert or update the "privilegio"** and it **doesn't give errors** in the log

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER Privilegio_Pagamento AFTER insert
ON pagamento FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare numero int(8);
    declare ordutente varchar(64);
    
    select count(*) into numero from pagamento where ordinante = new.ordinante and opera = new.opera;
    select username into ordutente from utente where email = new.ordinante;
    if (numero <> 0) then
        update privilegio P set P.volumi = concat(P.volumi, '-', new.volumi) where opera = new.opera and utente = ordutente;
    else 
        insert into privilegio(utente, opera, volumi) values(ordutente, new.opera, new.volumi);
    end if;
END
```

The interesting thing is that **each single line works alone** (the selects, the updates, the insert) so it seems that **what fails is the if-then-else**, since if I use something like this

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER Privilegio_Pagamento AFTER insert
ON pagamento FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare numero int(8);
    declare ordutente varchar(64);

    select count(*) into numero from pagamento where ordinante = new.ordinante and opera = new.opera;
    select username into ordutente from utente where email = new.ordinante;
    insert into privilegio(utente, opera, volumi) values(ordutente, new.opera, new.volumi);
END
```

It adds the the "privilegio".

To be sure I also tried this

```
select if (((select count(*) from pagamento where ordinante = 'abel.ligure73@virgilio.it' and opera = 'Problema Grande e Dama Rossa') <> 0), 'yes', 'no')
```

and **this works**.
What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

The answer of Gordon Linoff is correct but for my purpose it needs a concat like this `concat(volumi, '-', new.volumi)`.
Hope someone else will find it useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the logic, because you are counting rows in `pagamento` and then `insert`ing/`update`ing in `privilegio`.  That doesn't seem right.

In fact, the whole logic seems like it could be replaced with `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into privilegio (utente, opera, volumi)
    select u.username, new.opera, new.volumi
    from utente u
    where u.email = new.ordinante
    on duplicate key update volumi = concat(volumi, '-', new.volumi);
```

Comment: I didn't know about this method! I'll try tomorrow and I'll let you know how it goes. Anyway, in the database pagamento and privilegio are strictly connected, so if exist one pagamento then a "corresponding" privilegio exist

Comment: Hey, I tried it and it works very well! The only thing is that I had to modify the concat in this way "concat(volumi, '-', new.volumi)" since it has to use the old values of the row.
Anyway, you've been super useful and teached me something new, thanks!